# Is the number 1.1010010001... transcendental?

Tags: number-theory, real-numbers

Consider the number 1.1010010001... defined as 1.1 followed by linearly increasing numbers of zeroes separated by ones. This number must almost certainly be irrational, but is it also transcendental?

$$\sum_{i=1}^\infty 10^{-(i^2 -i)/2}$$

The number is superficially similar to Liouville's constant, but instead of containing a factorial in the sum there is a combination which is equivalent to (n-1)n/2, somewhat simpler algebraically.

It also appears to be related to the Jacobi-theta function.

If this constant is indeed irrational and transcendental what would be the best way to go about proving this?

Comment: If x is transcendental then (1+x) must also be. Thank you.